# How to disable google translator plug in and set margin-top: to 0px for body element?

Tags: css, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I'm currently use Google Translator plug in for my website

I have alaready

```
    .goog-te-banner-frame{
    visibility:hidden !important;
```

CSS property to disable Google translate bar on top.

But Google Translator has set margin-top:40px to body html tage as below code

```
  <body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 40px;">
```

So my website have 40px of top margin that make my website wrong with my default layout.

Please How can I set CSS or Javascript to modify my top margin to 0px;

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your CSS:

```css
body {
  top:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it was done and I can customize with icon and other layout

Answer (score 0):

If anybody want to do it by javascript, add this snippet to *document.ready*

```
var toolBar = document.getElementsByClassName('goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate')[0];
if(toolBar !== undefined) {
    toolBar.style.display  = 'none';
    document.body.style.top = '0px';
}
```

**How it works**:
Google loads the toolbar to an iframe whose class name is 'goog-te-banner-frame skiptranslate' and add 40px margin to top of html body. So we hide that frame and set body margin to '0px'.

**Note**: Refer to the attribution requirements by google https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.goog-te-banner-frame,
.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate,
.goog-te-gadget-icon {
display: none !important;
}
.skiptranslate {
display: none !important;
} 
.goog-logo-link {
display: none !important;
}
.goog-te-gadget {
color: transparent !important;
}
.goog-tooltip {
display: none !important;
}
.goog-tooltip:hover {
display: none !important;
}
.goog-text-highlight {
background-color: transparent !important;
border: none !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
}
.translated-ltr{margin-top: 0 !important;}
```